# How to insert multiple radio button values with Spring boot

Tags: html, spring, radio-button, sql-insert

I am making a test webpage with Spring boot. I would like to insert test answers in separate rows in my Oracle database.

App controller:

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public ModelAndView viewTestPage() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("testpage");
    Results result = new Results();
    mav.addObject("answers", answerService.getAllAnswers());
    mav.addObject("questions", questionService.getAllQuestion());
    mav.addObject("result", result);
    return mav;
}
@PostMapping("/results/save")  
private String saveOrUpdate(@ModelAttribute("result") Results result)  
{       
resultService.saveOrUpdate(result); 
return "redirect:/";  
}
```

ResultService:

```
@Autowired
    private ResultsRepository resultRepository;
    
    public void saveOrUpdate(Results result){
        Optional<Results> optionalEvent= this.resultRepository.findById(result.getId());
        if (optionalEvent.isPresent()) {
            throw new IdIsAlreadyExists("Result with id: " + result.getId() + " is already exists");
        }
        else resultRepository.save(result);
    }
```

Test.html:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/students/save}" th:object="${result}">
<table >
  <tr th:each="question : ${questions}">
    <!-- Question field -->
    <td  th:value="${question.qst_id}" th:text="${question.qst_title}"></td>
    <!-- Answer field -->
    <td th:text="${answers[0].answ_title}"></td>
    <td>
        <table >
            <tr>
            <td>1<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[0].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>2<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[1].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>3<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[2].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>4<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[3].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>5<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[4].answ_id}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${answers[4].answ_title}"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Test page:

[test looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI4Yz.png)

Database schema:

[student table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIX6i.png)

[answers table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Ae4s.png)

[questions table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCKcX.png)

[should insert 10+ question like these rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH32a.png)  <-- just inserted these rows manually as an example

for insert student_id i would use the username like "${#autentication.getName()}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can implement multiple (i.e more than two) radio buttons using form:radiobutton or form:radiobuttons tag

1. Using form:radiobuttons  with array list-

```
<form:radiobuttons path="passFailStatus" items="${passFailStatusList}" />
```

where passFailStatusLis is an arraylist.

2. Using form:radiobuttons with hash map

Comment: How can i reference to passFailStatusList in my controller ? Like this : @PostMapping("/results/save")  
private String saveOrUpdate(@RequestParam("passFailStatusList") ArrayList list ) {}  ?